# Issue with Primefaces rtl paginator

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

Problem in icons layout and positions in rtl.
Previous page icon should be swapped with next page icon as the direction in rtl is the opposite of ltr.

[image]

```
<p:dataTable  id="dataTable" var="myRequest" widgetVar="requestsTable" value="#{searchRequestsBB.model}" rows="10" paginator="true"
          paginatorPosition="bottom" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,50,100" selectionMode="single" selection="#{searchRequestsBB.selectedRequest}" rowKey="#{myRequest.id}" emptyMessage="#{langu['EMPTY_DATA_TABLE']}" lazy="true" resizableColumns="true">
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":content:detailsBtn, :content:detailsDlg" />
<p:column sortBy="#{myRequest.id}" headerText="#{langu['REQUEST_NUMBER']}" >
    <h:outputText value="#{myRequest.id}" />
</p:column>

<p:column sortBy="#{myRequest.requestDate}" headerText="#{langu['REQUEST_DATE']}" >
    <h:outputText value="#{myRequest.requestDate}">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{tripconf['datePatternShow']}" timeZone="Africa/Cairo"/>
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>

<p:column sortBy="#{myRequest.vehicleLicenseNumber}" headerText="#{langu['VEHICLE_LICENSE_NUMBER']}">
    <h:outputText value="#{myRequest.vehicleLicenseNumber}" />
</p:column>

<p:column sortBy="#{myRequest.chassisNumber}" headerText="#{langu['CHASSIS_NUMBER']}">
    <h:outputText value="#{myRequest.chassisNumber}" />
</p:column>

<p:column sortBy="#{myRequest.nationality.name}" headerText="#{langu['NATIONALITY']}">
    <f:facet name="filter">
        <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('requestsTable').filter()" effect="drop" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{langu['ALL']}" itemValue="#{null}"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{searchRequestsBB.countries}" var="country" itemLabel="#{country.name}" itemValue="#{country.id}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{myRequest.nationality.name}" />
</p:column>

<p:column sortBy="#{myRequest.totalDues}" headerText="#{langu['TOTAL_DUES']}">
    <h:outputText value="#{myRequest.totalDues}" />
</p:column>

<p:column sortBy="#{myRequest.requestStatus}" headerText="#{langu['status']}">
    <p:progressBar value="#{myRequest.requestStatus*25}" labelTemplate="{value}%" displayOnly="true"/>
</p:column></p:dataTable>
```

Note that my application supports rtl languages and ltr also.

Any ideas of how to solve ??

Comment: looks like your site CSS is making primefaces paginator huge

Comment: that's right, and what about the direction of the paginator buttons ??

Comment: The code in this picture,

http://i62.tinypic.com/1z3m8u8.jpg

Comment: I suggest you to add the code to the question you've made :-) [not an image, so we can copy and paste and try things in order to help you]

Comment: I appreciate your help.
I have added the required code.